# How can I populate this sort of mongoDB id data?

Tags: mongodb, populate

I have two Schemas:

```
AnswerSchema:{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ebe4b26b6fe863e4084a718"),
  "userId" : ObjectId("5ebd093989cae1746c348b2d"),
  "answersArray" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ebe4b26b6fe863e4084a71a"),
        "questionId" : ObjectId("5ebe31b22e13a22862f32ff7"),
        "answerId" : ObjectId("5ebe31b22e13a22862f32ffb")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ebe4b26b6fe863e4084a719"),
        "questionId" : ObjectId("5ebe32672e13a22862f32ffc"),
        "answerId" : ObjectId("5ebe32672e13a22862f32fff")
    }
  ],
  "__v" : 0
}
```

---

```
Question Schema{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ebe31b22e13a22862f32ff7"),
  "questionNumber" : 1,
  "options" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ebe31b22e13a22862f32ffb"),
        "image" : "/Qusetion1/Coffee.png",
        "title" : "Coffee"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ebe31b22e13a22862f32ffa"),
        "image" : "/Qusetion1/Drinks.png",
        "title" : "Drinks"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ebe31b22e13a22862f32ff9"),
        "image" : "/Qusetion1/Marijuana.png",
        "title" : "Marijuana"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ebe31b22e13a22862f32ff8"),
        "image" : "/Qusetion1/PreferNottoSay.png",
        "title" : "Prefer Not to Say"
    }
  ],
  "__v" : 0
}
```

This `answerId` field of `answerArray` is present in options of questionSchema
I want to populate `answerId` with the option matches with the `answerId`.

Query I am using is:

```
let filter = {
    userId: req.userInfo
}
models.answers.find(filter).populate([{
        path:('answersArray.answerId'),
        model:('Question'),
        select:('options')     
    },
    {
        path:('answersArray.questionId'),
        model:('Question'),
        select:('questionNumber')
    }
]).exec((err, result) => {   
    console.log(result)
    if(err) {
        response.status(400).send({
            success: false,
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        })

    } else {
        response.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            message: "User Profile",
        })
    }
})
```

---

This is giving me

```
{
    "_id": "5ebe4b26b6fe863e4084a718",
    "userId": "5ebd093989cae1746c348b2d",
    "answersArray": [
        {
            "_id": "5ebe4b26b6fe863e4084a71a",
            "questionId": {
                "_id": "5ebe31b22e13a22862f32ff7",
                "questionNumber": 1
            },
            "answerId": null
        },
        {
            "_id": "5ebe4b26b6fe863e4084a719",
            "questionId": {
                "_id": "5ebe32672e13a22862f32ffc",
                "questionNumber": 2                            
            },
            "answerId": null
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

This is result from query

---

What I am expecting is

```
{
    "_id": "5ebe4b26b6fe863e4084a718",
    "userId": "5ebd093989cae1746c348b2d",
    "answersArray": [
        {
            "_id": "5ebe4b26b6fe863e4084a71a",
            "questionId": {
                "_id": "5ebe31b22e13a22862f32ff7",
                "questionNumber": 1
            },
            "answerId": {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ebe31b22e13a22862f32ffb"),
                "image" : "/Qusetion1/Coffee.png",
                "title" : "Coffee"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "5ebe4b26b6fe863e4084a719",
            "questionId": {
                "_id": "5ebe32672e13a22862f32ffc",
                "questionNumber": 2
             },
             "answerId": {
                 "_id" : ObjectId("5ebe32672e13a22862f32fff"),
                 "image" : "/Qusetion1/Drinks.png",
                 "title" : "Drinks"
             }
        }
    ],
}
```

This is what I am expecting from it.

So basically I want to populate the field `answerId` from the options.

Comment: Your question is now open again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is in these lines:

```
{
    path:('answersArray.answerId'),
    model:('Question'),
    select:('options')     
}
```

It isn't clear in the question but doesn't `answerId` point to Answer _id? If so should this be `model:('Answer')` and remove `select:('options')` as that doesn't exist in Answer schema